# How to understand patterns defined in TextMate?

Tags: textmate, textmate2, textmate-1.5

I am learning TextMate in order to define customized keyword for highlighting in a Orion editor(A browser based editor who is using TextMate grammar). I read this link http://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars.html#language_rules. And I don't understand how to define a pattern to match a keyword.

Below is an example I tried to define `database` as a keyword. But it doesn't get recognized by the editor.

```
     {  name = 'keyword.control.db';
        match = '\b(database)\b';
     }
```

what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Your match regex looks good to me. Did you set a grammar and file types in the language's settings panel?

Comment: I am running in standard along application. There is no server setup. Everything is in client side. So there is no setting panel.

Comment: When I say settings panel: Bundles -> Edit Bundles -> (Your Bundle) -> Language Grammars -> (Your Language), there's a drawer on that window.

Comment: These is no settings panel in my window. Are you talking about Orion server?